# Simple Address Book- Python

Tags: python

I am a Python beginner (well, a newbie programmer). I am creating a small address book, just as a fun project, nothing too serious. I would appreciate if you review it and advise me on how to make it better (not complete yet). Here's the link:

https://github.com/volf52/address-book

Here's the code:

**main.py**

```
import contact
import addressBook
import re
from sys import exit
import random


__author__ = 'Muhammad Arslan <rslnkrmt2552@gmail.com>'

app = addressBook.addressBook(str(raw_input("Enter name of book  (Will be created if doesn't exist) \n> ")))
main_menu = '\n1. Show all contacts.\n2. Add contact.\n3. Search.\n4. Delete a contact.\n5.Update contact.\n6. Exit\n\n>'

def exitProg():
    exitMessages = ['You have my permission to die.']
    print random.choice(exitMessages)
    exit(0)

def getOption(prompt):
    inp = raw_input(prompt)
    try:
        inp = int(inp)
    except ValueError:
        print 'You should have selected a proper option.'
        return 13
    return inp


def showContacts():
    print 'show all'

def addContact():
    flag = 13
    while flag == 13:
        exp = map(lambda x: re.compile(x), [r'^([a-zA-Z]+)$', r'^(\+)?(\d)+$', r"(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)"])

        fName = str(raw_input('Enter first name : ')).strip()
        while not exp[0].match(fName):
            fName = str(raw_input('\nWrong Input\nEnter (proper) first name : ')).strip()

        lName = str(raw_input('Enter last name : ')).strip()
        while not exp[0].match(lName):
            lName = str(raw_input('\nWrong Input\nEnter (proper) last name : ')).strip()

        pNum = str(raw_input('Enter phone number : ')).strip()
        while not exp[1].match(pNum):
            pNum = str(raw_input('\nWrong Input\nEnter (proper) number : ')).strip()

        email = str(raw_input('Enter email(Blank for none) : ')).strip()
        while not exp[2].match(email):
            if not email:
                break
            email = str(raw_input('\nWrong Input\nEnter (proper) email : ')).strip()

        print app.addEntry(contact.Contact(fName, lName, pNum, email))

        while (flag < 1) or (flag > 3):
            flag = getOption('\n1. Add another.\n2. Go to main menu\n3. Exit.\n\n> ')
        if flag == 2:
            break
        elif flag == 3:
            exitProg()
        else:
            flag = 13

def searchContact():
    print 'search'

def removeContact():
    name = str(raw_input('Enter first name of the contact: '))
    print app.removeEntry(name)

def updateContact():
    name = str(raw_input('Enter the first name of the contact: '))
    msg, cont = app.searchEntry(name)
    print msg



funcs = [showContacts, addContact, searchContact, removeContact, updateContact, exitProg]

while True:
    inp = getOption(main_menu)
    while inp < 1 or inp > 6:
        print 'Input a proper number, moron.'
        inp = getOption(main_menu)
    funcs[inp - 1]()
```

**contact.py**

```
__author__ = 'Muhammad Arslan <rslnkrmt2552@gmail.com>'

class Contact(object):
    """Initialize a new contact object.
    Takes in name and phone number. Other arguments are optional."""
    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname, pNumber, email = ''):
        super(Contact, self).__init__()
        self.__firstName = firstname.lower()
        self.__lastName = lastname.lower()
        self.__pNumber = pNumber
        self.__email = email

    def __str__(self):
        return self.getName() + '\t' + self.getNumber()

    def __eq__(self , other):
        return (self.getName() == other.getName()) or (self.getNumber() == other.getNumber())

    def getName(self):
        return self.__firstName[0].upper()+self.__firstName[1:] + ' ' + self.__lastName[0].upper() + self.__lastName[1:]

    def getFirstName(self):
        return self.__firstName

    def getLastName(self):
        return self.__lastName

    def getNumber(self):
        return self.__pNumber

    def getEmail(self):
        return self.__email

    def setFirstName(self, newFName):
        self.__firstName = newFName

    def setLastName(self, newLName):
        self.__lastName = newLName

    def setName(self, fullName):
        self.__firstName, self.__lastName = fullName.split(' ')

    def setNumber(self, newNumber):
        self.__pNumber = newNumber

    def setEmail(self, newEmail):
        self.__email = newEmail
```

**addressBook.py**

```
try:
    import cPickle as pickle
except:
    import pickle
from hashlib import sha256

__author__ = 'Muhammad Arslan <rslnkrmt2552@gmail.com>'


class addressBook():
    """Class : Addressbook"""
    def __init__(self, name):
        try:
            self.__name = self.createName(name)+ '.db'
            self.__db = open(self.__name, 'rb')
            self.__entries = pickle.load(self.__db)
            self.__db.close()
        except:
            self.__db = open(self.__name, 'wb')
            self.__entries = {}
            self.__db.close()

    def __update(self):
        self.__db = open(self.__name, 'wb')
        pickle.dump(self.__entries, self.__db, -1)
        self.__db.close()

    def addEntry(self, contact):
        name = contact.getFirstName()
        if name in self.__entries:
            return '\nContact already present.\n'
        else:
            self.__entries[name] = contact
            self.__update()
            return '\nContact added successfully.\n'

    def removeEntry(self, name):
        if name in self.__entries:
            del self.__entries[name]
            self.__update()
            return '\nContact removed successfully.\n'
        else:
            return '\nName not found.\n'

    def searchEntry(self, name):
        name = name.lower()
        if name in self.__entries:
            return ('Contact found.', self.__entries[name])
        else:
            return ('Contact not found.', None)

    def updateEntry(self, name, param, val):
        name = name.lower()
        val = val.lower()

        if name in self.__entries:
            k = self.__entries[name]
            funcs = [k.setFirstName, k.setLastName, k.setName, k.setNumber, k.setEmail]
            funcs[param-1](val)
            return '\nContact updated successfully.\n'
        else:
            return '\nName not found.\n'

    @staticmethod
    def createName(mName):
        hsh = sha256(mName).hexdigest()
        return ''.join(hsh[1::3])
```

Comment: Why have you written all of those no-op getters and setters? [Python isn't Java](http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html), see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/2627002/3001761 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/6618002/3001761 for how you can make an attribute private *if and when you actually need to*.

Comment: I wanted to restrict access to the "database" file, and make the code a bit more secure. (Although you are right ... I do come from a Java background, so thanks for providing the link to that awesome article).

Comment: That's reasonable (although I'm not sure `__name_mangling` is needed). I meant those like `firstName` where you have a getter and a setter for no reason; they just pass straight through.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like partially mentioned in the comments, you should use `__setattr__(self, name, value)` and `__getattr__(self, name)` for security if needed, and otherwise just allow direct access, instead of get_* and set_* functions.
You can also use `@property` on individual attributes.